# Website alternatively showing error on Netlify (Contentful + Next.js)

Tags: next.js, netlify, contentful

I have deployed a Next.js (V14) + Contentful website on Netlify

All my builds are working

But my front page randomly shows either ok or shows a

element with some text inside

Here is a snapshot of the webpage when the error is showing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOYNz.png)

I have no error in my console

Here is the website

https://debre-architecte.netlify.app

The build is ok

Unfortunately the problem appears / disappears every 1 or 2 hours

If someone already had the same issue, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

OK  eventually it seems to be a problem with ISR (incremental static regeneration) with Netlify which seems not supported properly

I will try to find the solution (without removing ISR)